# Exclude values from polynomial fit in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to exclude certain values from a polynomial fit to data in a pandas data frame. At the moment my code is:

```
d = np.polyfit(df1['S_B'],df1['log_norm'],1)
f = np.poly1d(d)
df1['predicted']=getExp(f(df1['S_B']))*df1['Cl']
```

Is it possible to exclude the values in column `log_norm` at rows 0,1 and 6 in the polynomial fit?

The code to get the getExp function is below

```
from math import e
def getExp(n):
 return e**n
```

Comment: Will you please send the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())`?

Comment: {'radius': {0: 1.16, 1: 1.143, 2: 1.126, 3: 1.109, 4: 1.079}, 'Cl': {0: 0.2472, 1: 0.6308, 2: 0.095, 3: 0.4793, 4: 0.1542}, 'ppm': {0: 0.02, 1: 12.3, 2: 0.049, 3: 0.62, 4: 2.04}, 'log_norm': {0: -2.514465452029545, 1: 2.9703656862716254, 2: -0.6620565934899141, 3: 0.2573927718735516, 4: 2.582454625709033}, 'S_B': {0: 0.028654166666666633, 1: 0.024317783999999995, 2: 0.0203732853333333, 3: 0.016810844666666654, 4: 0.011426114666666652}, 'predicted': {0: 0.030737394206049023, 1: 0.30581914467723303, 2: 0.15879826378664794, 3: 2.450262190376278, 4: 4.270815301694465}}

Comment: Will you please add the code for the `getExp` function to the question"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create a new dataframe where you have [dropped](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the rows you don't want:

```
df2 = df1.drop(index=[0, 1, 6])
```

An alternative would be to make these rows NaN in the `log_norm` column, but `np.polyfit` might throw an error, in which case you would need to drop these rows anyway.

Comment: Yes, I had tried to replace the values with NaN but polyfit does throw an error. It seems making a new data frame is best! Thanks